# Drag Sensitivity in ParallelCoordinates with Drag and Drop

Tags: highcharts

I am having difficulties getting drag sensitivity to be similar across different y axis with different ranges.
The sample code can be found here
https://jsfiddle.net/dalesh/xnvompad/4/
The second and third Y axes dont have the same drag and drop speed across the axis as the first 1 . It appears to be tied to the range of the first Y axis.

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/draggable-points.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/parallel-coordinates.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="parallel.css">
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>


<div id="container"></div>
<script src="parallel.js"></script>
```

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'spline',
    parallelCoordinates: true,
    parallelAxes: {
        lineWidth: 2
    }
},
title: {
    text: 'Parallel Plot'
},

xAxis: {
    categories: [
        'Miles / 100',
        'Miles / 10',
        'Miles '
    ],
},
yAxis: [ {
    min: 0,
    max: 0.1
}, {
  min: 0,
  max: 1
}, {
  min: 0,
  max: 10
}],
series: [
    {
        name: 'Runner 1',
        data: [
          {y:0.05,
            x:0,
            dragDrop: {
              draggableY: true,
              //dragPrecisionY:0.001,

            },
            marker: {
              enabled:true,
              symbol: 'triangle',
              width:25,
              height:25
            },
          },
          
           {y:0.5,
            x:1,
            dragDrop: {
              draggableY: true,
              dragPrecisionY:0.01,

            },
            marker: {
              enabled:true,
              symbol: 'triangle',
              width:25,
              height:25
            },
          },
          {y:5,
            x:2,
             dragDrop: {
               draggableY: true,
               //dragPrecisionY:0.1,
             },
             marker: {
              enabled:true,
              symbol: 'triangle',
              width:25,
              height:25
            },
           },
          ],
        shadow: false,
        dragDrop: {
          draggableY: true,
        },
        
    }
]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because all of your points are tied only to the first `yAxis`, look: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tgcyz9sf/

Notice that the `max` and `min` limit the chart plot.

Only series can be tied to a particular `yAxis`, not points: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.yAxis

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rnjda0gh/

Comment: Thanks Sebastian , thanks for the clarification . Let me see how I can work around with  what you have suggested .